# Pandas: DataFrame groupby for year/month and return with new DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I need some directions in grouping a Pandas `DateFrame` object by year or month and get in return an new `DateFrame` object with a new index.
Here is my code so far. `groupby` works as intended.

Load data from .csv file, parse 'Date' to date format (historical stock quotes from finance.yahoo.com)

```
In [23]: import pandas as pd
         file = pd.read_csv("sdf.de.csv", parse_dates=['Date'])
         file.head(2)

Out[23]:
    Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Adj Close
0   2016-02-16  18.650  18.70   17.940  18.16   1720800 17.0600
1   2016-02-15  18.295  18.64   18.065  18.50   1463500 17.3794
```

sort file for 'Date' ascending and set index to `Date`

```
In [24]: daily = file.sort_values(by='Date').set_index('Date')
         daily.head()

Out[24]:
            Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                        
2000-01-03  14.20   14.50   14.15   14.40   277400  2.7916
2000-01-04  14.29   14.30   13.90   14.15   109200  2.7431
```

grouping for month

I would do an additional `apply()` to the groups, which would condense the data for the specific group, e.g. find the highest `High` value for the year/month or `sum()` the `Volume` values. This step is omitted for this example.

```
In [39]: monthly = daily.groupby(lambda x: (x.year, x.month))
         monthly.first()

Out[39]:
            Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Adj Close
(2000, 1)   14.200  14.500  14.150  14.400  277400  2.7916
(2000, 2)   13.900  14.390  13.900  14.250  287200  2.7625
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
(2016, 1)   23.620  23.620  23.620  23.620  0       22.1893
(2016, 2)   19.575  19.630  19.140  19.450  1783000 18.2719
```

This works, but it gives me a `DateFrame` object with a tuple as index.

The desired result, in this case for grouping for month, would be a complete new `DataFrame` object, but the `Date` index should be a new `DatetimeIndex` in the form of `%Y-%m` or just `%Y` if grouped by year.

```
Out[39]:
        Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date
2000-01 14.200  14.500  14.150  14.400  277400  2.7916
2000-02 13.900  14.390  13.900  14.250  287200  2.7625
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2016-01 23.620  23.620  23.620  23.620  0       22.1893
2016-02 19.575  19.630  19.140  19.450  1783000 18.2719
```

I'm thankful for any directions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `daily.index.year, daily.index.month` or change `index` [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index`:

```
print daily
              Open   High    Low  Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                       
2000-01-01  14.200  14.50  14.15  14.40   277400     2.7916
2000-02-01  13.900  14.39  13.90  14.25   287200     2.7625
2016-01-01  23.620  23.62  23.62  23.62        0    22.1893
2016-02-01  19.575  19.63  19.14  19.45  1783000    18.2719

print daily.groupby([daily.index.year, daily.index.month]).first()
          Open   High    Low  Close   Volume  Adj Close
2000 1  14.200  14.50  14.15  14.40   277400     2.7916
     2  13.900  14.39  13.90  14.25   287200     2.7625
2016 1  23.620  23.62  23.62  23.62        0    22.1893
     2  19.575  19.63  19.14  19.45  1783000    18.2719

daily.index = daily.index.to_period('M')
print daily.groupby(daily.index).first()
           Open   High    Low  Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                    
2000-01  14.200  14.50  14.15  14.40   277400     2.7916
2000-02  13.900  14.39  13.90  14.25   287200     2.7625
2016-01  23.620  23.62  23.62  23.62        0    22.1893
2016-02  19.575  19.63  19.14  19.45  1783000    18.2719
```

Comment: thanks, the last example works perfectly. but strangely, if i rerun this cell, I get an Attribute Error`----> 4 daily.index = daily.index.to_period('M')
      5 monthly = daily.groupby(daily.index).first()
      6 print (monthly)
AttributeError: 'PeriodIndex' object has no attribute 'to_period'` I have to rerun **all** cells to make this work

Comment: IIUC you need set to `PeriodIndex` only once `daily.index = daily.index.to_period('M')` and then use other code. Try testing: `print daily`, `daily.index = daily.index.to_period('M')` and `print daily`

Comment: but it changes the `PeriodIndex` of `daily` permanently. If I want to change it back to `daily.index = daily.index.to_period('D')`for days or work further with `daily.index = daily.index.to_period('A')`for year, I get the AttributeError

Comment: So then maybe is better use columns instead of index like: `daily['m'] = daily.index.to_period('M')` and `monthly = daily.groupby('m').first()`, then `daily['d'] = daily.index.to_period('D')` and `daily1 = daily.groupby('d').first()`

Comment: Or you van remember `index` to column like `df['i'] = df.index` and then use `groupby`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I try leaving the index an integer, then setting `Month`and `Year`columns. Than group with `monthly = daily.groupby(['Month'])`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to access the year and month accessor variable from your timestamps and then group on those.

```
>>> df.groupby([[d.year for d in df.Date], [d.month for d in df.Date]]).first()
             Date    Open   High    Low  Close   Volume  Adj_Close
2000 1 2000-01-01  14.200  14.50  14.15  14.40   277400     2.7916
     2 2000-02-01  13.900  14.39  13.90  14.25   287200     2.7625
2016 1 2016-01-01  23.620  23.62  23.62  23.62        0    22.1893
     2 2016-02-01  19.575  19.63  19.14  19.45  1783000    18.2719
```